# How to loop through selected data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select multiple rows of data from a table and add it onto another one.

For example:

```
Select * from Table1
```

which would return

```
id | name
 1 | Chad
 2 | Mary
 3 | Denise
```

I want to add these rows of data to Table 2

```
Insert(id, name)
values(@id, @name)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Table2(id,name)
SELECT t.id,t.name
FROM Table1 t
;
```